# Accessing individual dataframes from a split function in R

Tags: r, list, split

I'm new to R am trying reorganise my data based on the sampleID
I've used the split() function in R which has does exactly what I wanted it to and stored my information in new data.frames
My question is now that they are in separate data.frames how do I access them individually for further processing?
My code goes as follows

```
splitList.list = list()

for (i in 1:31)
{
  splitList.list[[i]] = split(chromList.list[[i]], chromList.list[[i]]$sampleID)
}

splitList.list[[1]]
```

I take the files I have (31 files), split them and store them in a list. This much works. I get an output that looks like this 
[image]

This can be repeated with any of list elements and work. I now what to do some processing on separately on each data.frame but don't know how to access just one of these. Please help

Comment: You can use `lapply`

Comment: As I understand you, `chromeList.list` is a list of data frames that you subdivided into individual data frames based on `sample$ID` so now `splitList.list` is a list of lists. You would access the first data frame in the first file as `splitList.list[[1]][[1]]`.

Comment: Thanks dcarlson that is exactly what I needed. I knew how to access this type of thing if I in another language but the syntax for R isn't something I'm familiar with